# How to enable all input methods is AOSP?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-source, android-settings

I found Preference fragment (com.android.settings.inputmethod.InputMethodAndSubtypeEnabler.java https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/inputmethod/InputMethodAndSubtypeEnabler.java),

where I can enable all input methods.
I tried to understand where these preference is saved in order to set default values. But I can't :(
Code is not clear.

May be someone know where I can set default input methods programmatically.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about your goal / what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Task is about setting some set of layouts as default value.
In "standard" Android by default we have system language layout.
I should set by default few layouts